# postgis-2.0.dll could not be found

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I have installed PostgreSQL 2 and the pgAdmin III.
I am trying to access the databases installed there (postgis20), but I am getting this message: 
`ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgis-2.0.dll": The specified procedure could not be found`

The .dll file is there in the folder, and I tried reinstalling many times (even other version of postgres), but still doesn't work.

Also when I try to query `create extension pgrouting;` I am getting the same message.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't know if this will help but you do know to access postgis libs you have to "create extension postgis"?

Comment: @AdamBenson Yes, I already created postgis extension.